# How do I make the contacts appear in alphabetical order for this particular code?

Tags: android, eclipse

How do I make the contacts appear in alphabetical order for this particular code? Should there be changes in the `dataadapter` class as well?

```
       public class Contacts extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        Button addcon, selcon, ok, back,search;
       dataadapter dap;
       ArrayList<String> name;


       ArrayList<String> data;
        ListView lv;
       adapter adp;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aadp;
    Intent it;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts);

        // database adapter
        dap = new dataadapter(Contacts.this);

        // objects for buttons
        addcon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        selcon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selected);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);


        // action to buttons
        addcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        selcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);


        // array list declaration
        name = new ArrayList<String>();

        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        data = dap.getData();

        // contacts
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        // object cursor for contacts
        Cursor cur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null,null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                name.add(cur
                        .getString(
                                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
                        .toString());// contacts name it will return to
                                        // arraylist

            } while (cur.moveToNext());

        }
        // setting list view

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         lv = (ListView)findViewById (R.id.listView1);
            lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);






        // selected contacts
        aadp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

        lv.setAdapter(aadp);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.contacts:
            // add or edit
            adp = new adapter();
            lv.setAdapter(adp);
            break;
        case R.id.back:
            // back to main screen

            it = new Intent(Contacts.this, BlackcallsActivity.class);
            it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(it);
            break;
        case R.id.selected:
            // selected contacts
            aadp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

            lv.setAdapter(aadp);

            break;
        case R.id.save:
            // saving contacts in dataabase
            ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null,null);
            String id,
            Name,
            ph = "";

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    id = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    Name = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int hasno = cur
                            .getInt(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

                        if (Name.equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(i).toString())) {

                            if (hasno == 1) {
                                Cursor pcur = cr
                                        .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                                null,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                        + "=?",
                                                new String[] { id }, null);
                                if (pcur.moveToFirst()) {
                                    ph = pcur
                                            .getString(pcur
                                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                    String[] s1 = ph.split("-");
                                    ph = "";
                                    for (int j = 0; j < s1.length; j++) {

                                        ph += s1[j].trim();
                                    }
                                    num.add(ph);
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }

            dap.insert(data, num);

            Toast.makeText(Contacts.this, "CONTACTS SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            it = new Intent(Contacts.this, BlackcallsActivity.class);
            it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(it);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    class adapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater lf = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = lf.inflate(R.layout.checklist, null);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cname);
            final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            tv.setText(name.get(position));
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                if (data.get(i).equals(tv.getText())) {
                    cb.setChecked(true);

                }

            }

            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public  void  onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    String s = (String) tv.getText();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {

                        data.add(s);

                    } else {

                        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

                            if (s.equals(data.get(i))) {
                                data.remove(i);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return    convertView;
        }
    }

    @Override

    protected  void  onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        dap.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should edit your question to be more specific. Show what approach you were trying. Pasting large amounts of code will discourage people from trying to help you.

Comment: From the question, I only got an idea that you want returned data to be in Alphabetical Order, Check this link, there is a param for Sort Order
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String%29